# Case-sensitive search with `smartcase` set

Tags: search, letter-case

I have `set smartcase` in my `init.vim` so searching with `/lowercase` is case-insensitive, which is usually what I want. However, I sometimes want to do a case-sensitive search where my target is all lowercase, like `/include`.

I know that prepending a search with `\c` as in `/\csearch` makes the whole search case-insensitive.

Is there a quick way (maybe similar to the `\c`) with `smartcase` set to make just 1 search instance case-sensitive without using uppercase characters in the search?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `\C` to force the pattern to be case-sensitive.

See [`:help /\C`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5CC), which explains it alongside `\c`:

> `\C` does the opposite: Force matching case for the whole pattern.

In your specific case: `/\Cinclude` will search for only the lowercase matches of "include".